# Re-Authenticate User after Email Change Firebase React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have built a feature that allows a logged in User to update their email. When I change the email and redirect to a different page the email that is displayed is the old email, and only when I refresh the page does the new email appear. I believe the the best way to address this is for the system to re-authenticate the User (I may be wrong and am open to suggestions).

```
// UpdateEmail.js

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  this.props.updateEmail(this.state.newEmail)

  this.props.history.push('/settings')
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateEmail: (newEmail) => dispatch(updateEmail(newEmail))
  }
}

// authActions.js *NEW*

export const updateEmail = (newEmail, oldEmail, password) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    let credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(oldEmail, password);

    user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
      .then(() => {
        user.updateEmail(
          newEmail
        ).then(() => {
          dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_LOGIN_DETAILS_SUCCESS'})

          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
              dispatch({
                type: 'CHECK_REAUTH_SUCCESS',
                user: user
              })
            } else {
              dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_REAUTH_ERROR'})
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_LOGIN_DETAILS_ERROR'}, err)
        })
      })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: 'REAUTH_ERROR'}, err)
    })
  }
}

// Settings.js this is where the user is redirected after CHECK_REAUTH_SUCCESS

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    licenses: state.firestore.ordered.licenses,
    aircraft: state.firestore.ordered.aircraft,
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  }
}

// authActions.js *OLD*

export const updateEmail = (newEmail) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser

    user.updateEmail(
      newEmail
    ).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_LOGIN_EMAIL_SUCCESS'})
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_LOGIN_EMAIL_ERROR', err })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: that literally means you're invalidation your `session` if any, which means you must `log` the user `out` and redirect him/her to `login` page

Comment: That makes sense. There are many systems out there that allow you update the email without logging the user out. Maybe I can have a modal that requests the new login details, allowing the User to Re-Authenticate. Would this be a good User experience?

Comment: Or maybe I should make it that the User also has to input the current password in order to change the email, then after email update I can use the new email and the password to Re-Authenticate?

Comment: yes, that's the way. I was about to comment the same :)

Comment: So I tried to reauthenticate the User before the updateEmail function and after, but when redirected to where the info is displayed it still shows the old email.

Comment: :) you, probably, need to update the `state` too

Comment: I have done some tests and @manish you are right I need to update the `state`, but how do I do that? If you look at the Settings.js `mapStateToProps` I access the `auth` info from `state.firebase.auth`.

Comment: that's fine, make sure your call to `mapStateToProps` passes the `updated state`